# How to invoke function in geth

Tags: solidity, web3js, go-ethereum

I got a error. when invoke a function in geth after I deployed a smart contract in my private chain.

[image]

my contract code is below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract Storage{
    uint256 public value = 5;
    function set(uint256 number) public{
        value = number;
    }
    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256){
        return value;
    }
}
```

I want to know how to solve this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the GETH console, you can run the [JSON-RPC API](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/) methods by passing the request object to the console, as well as their [JavaScript alternatives](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interacting-with-geth/javascript-console#interactive-use).

I don't have a GETH instance available now to verify, but this should work:

```
eth.call(
    to: "0xcontractAddress",
    data: "0x2e64cec1"
);
```

I'm assuming the `eth.call` method from the other examples mentioned in the docs, as well as from the [web3](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.0/web3-eth.html#call) method.

The `data` field is selector of the specific function. First 4 bytes of keccak-256 hash of the string `retrieve()`.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, but it still had got a error "Invalid address" :((